# Android multi-touch feature (up to 6 touches)

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch

I want to know if it is possible to make an android application that features up to 6 touches simultaneously with the multi-touch option (not just two). Please can u help me to find some relevant literature. I've found some answers here on stackoverflow, but i am afraid that that's not enough.

I would appreciate every help. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devices that support "jazzhands" will handle up to 10 simultaneous touches. Your app can require jazzhands support via the following manifest element:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand" />
```

Not all devices will support this -- for example, the Kindle Fire only supports two simultaneous touches IIRC.

Comment: This will definitely get me a new start. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

There is no software difference between 2 or 6 touches (except for the permission), it is hardware related and if you can't use more of 2 fingers then you should try on another device.

Anyway, if you want good multitouch litterature, have a look here:

[Making sense of multitouch (android-developers.blogspot.fr)](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)