# Android device detects only 2 fingers max but feature JAZZHAND exists

Tags: android, device, touchscreen

I need to detect 3 fingers in my app but some devices can only detect 2 touches max.

But all multitouch features are present when I check:

```
hasSystemFeature ( "FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH" ); >> TRUE
hasSystemFeature ( "FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT" ); >> TRUE
hasSystemFeature ( "FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND" ); >> TRUE
```

The JAZZHAND feature means that the device can handle 5+ touches !?

See this post too: [Android multi-touch feature (up to 6 touches)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346882/android-multi-touch-feature-up-to-6-touches)